# How to Run a Rundeck Job via One-liner Curl Command with an Option Value?

Tags: rundeck

I'm planning on running a one liner curl command like this:

```
https://rundeck.url.com/api/1/job/${job_id_here}/run?authtoken=${token_here}&Message=hello
```

wherein the `Message` is an option or if a variable inside a Rundeck job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
curl --data-urlencode "argString=-optionname value" http://yourhost:4440/api/29/job/${your-job-id}/run?authtoken=${your-auth-token}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! May I ask what Rundeck version you're using? I'm having an error when using /api/18 and above but I'm using Rundeck version 3.0.9 already.

Comment: I use 3.0.13 (API 29) for Rundeck 3.0.9 you can use the API 27.

Comment: Thank you, found out that a normal `curl` command only uses GET, I should use -XPOST to use the API 18 version feature.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
curl -D - \
-X "POST" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: j97rbzw19u9pT1a0JvQTcmFuzaFYW71W" \
-d "{\"argString\":\" -servername $servername -foldername $foldername \"}" \
http://192.168.43.50:4440/api/16/job/c0649a32-1264-47fd-a345-e061794b2326/executions
```