# How do I pass parameters from Jenkins to Rundeck?

Tags: jenkins, rundeck

I am new to Rundeck and I managed to create project, nodes and jobs in Rundeck

I created a simple parameterized job in Jenkins and I input IP Address (eg 10.10.20.30)

I would like to pass $IP_ADDRESS `from Jenkins to Rundeck.`

I tried adding `ip_address=$IP_ADDRESS` in Jenkins post-build action of Rundeck but I am unable to `echo IP_ADDRESS` from Rundeck

I googled a lot but I did not get enough information.  Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can point to Rundeck job with options using Rundeck API like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593735/10426011 but the best way to integrate Rundeck with Jenkins is to use the Rundeck plugin for Jenkins, check this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin

Comment: I used Rundeck plugin, but in addition I used EnvInject Plugin on Jenkins to pass environment variables to Rundeck